# How can I create a systemd service that depends on a file from a snap?

Tags: systemd, snap

I have a systemd service that depends on the Google Cloud SDK (specifically the `gsutil` command), which is unfortunately installed as a Snap.

When my system boots up, my service sometimes starts before the Snap is ready to be used (`/bin/snap/gsutil` does not yet exist and neither does `/snap/google-cloud-sdk/current`).

I'm currently working around this with a loop that checks for the existence of `/bin/snap/gsutil` in the prestart script for my service but that feels rather ugly.

Is there a neat way to wait for a particular Snap to be ready to use before calling it? I have tried starting after `snapd.seeded.service` which does not appear to be sufficient.

Comment: Have you found the answer on your question ? I have similar issue when systemd service depends on snap.*.service